# Optaplanner: do not exhaust facts after an assignment

Tags: optaplanner

I'm working with a variant of the RVP with overconstraining.
I have a list of "customers" that are assigned to a single "vehicle" up to its capacity, and a ghost "vehicle" takes all "customers" that have not been assigned to the main one.

I was wondering if there is a way to allow the main "vehicle" to have duplicate "customers" (or even more than two identical "customers").
I think it might be possible by providing multiple times the same "customers" but I haven't tried it, as it seems to unnecessarily complicate the formulation of the problem.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**
I have tried providing duplicate facts and it works. I'm still looking for a more elegant solution though.